# How to sort and append a list in Python from txt file?

Tags: python, file

I have an issue with reading string from file and store it to sorted list
Here is my code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list(fh)
for line in lst:
  line = line.rstrip()
  line = line.split()
```

print (line)

Comment: Do you mind sharing your file text?

Comment: And what is the issue you mentioned?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

lst = list()
for line in fh:
    for l in line.split():
        if l not in lst:
           lst.append(l)
 lst.sort()        
 print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am conflicted about the sorting you are looking for.
So I will cover my three best guesses:

1. sorting the lines of the file:
   `lst = sorted(list(fh))`
   will sort the file's lines in alphabetic order.
2. sorting each line of the file: `line = sorted(line.split())` will sort the words in each line.
3. sorting all the words in the file:

   ```
    fname = input("Enter file name: ")
    fh = open(fname, "r")
    content = sorted(sum([line.rstrip().split() for line in fh.readlines()], [])) # Less lines the better :)
    print(content) # Will print a list of the sorted words of the file.
   ```

   (`sum([...],[])` makes a list inside a list to one list.)